# JAVA - Figuring out the difference

Tags: java

I'm given the problem below, however I'm unable to have it pass all the tests no matter what approach I take. Could anyone point out where I'm going wrong?

The problem has to be solved using Math.abs() and IF statements, no loops/functions/etc.

```
////////////////////////////// PROBLEM STATEMENT //////////////////////////////
// Given three ints, a b c, print true if one of b or c is "close"           //
// (differing from a by at most 1), while the  other is "far", differing     //
// from both other values by 2 or more. Note: Math.abs(num) computes the     //
// absolute value of a number.                                               //
//   1, 2, 10 -> true                                                        //
//   1, 2, 3 -> false                                                        //
//   4, 1, 3 -> true                                                         //
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

My code:

```
  if ((Math.abs(a-b) <= 1 || Math.abs(a+b) <= 1) && (Math.abs(a-c) >= 2 || Math.abs(a+c) >= 2)) {

    if (Math.abs(a-c) >= 2 || Math.abs(a+c) >= 2) {
      System.out.println("true");
    } else {
      System.out.println("false");
    }

  } else if (Math.abs(a-c) <= 1 || Math.abs(a+c) <= 1) {

    if (Math.abs(a-b) >= 2 || Math.abs(a+b) >= 2) {
      System.out.println("true");
    } else {
      System.out.println("false");
    } 

  } else {
     System.out.println("false"); 
    }
```

Comment: What you want to do ? Math.abs() will always return >=0.

Comment: Your positive cases are wrong; you want the difference between two values but Math.abs(a+b) will return 5 for the last scenario when the difference is 3.  You want abs(b-a) and the same applies to all your checks.

Comment: @Bob Thanks a heap, I didn't pick up on that and it made all the difference!

Answer (score 1):

Seems overly complex, you might want to go for something more simple:

```
boolean abIsClose = Math.abs(a-b) <= 1;
boolean acIsClose = Math.abs(a-c) <= 1;
boolean bcIsClose = Math.abs(b-c) <= 1;
boolean result = abIsClose && !acIsClose && !bcIsClose;
result = result || (!abIsClose && acIsClose && !bcIsClose);
result = result || (!abIsClose && !acIsClose && bcIsClose);
```

Abs always gives a positive number, that way you don't need to confirm a value is between -1 and 1, you only need to confirm <= 1.

Comment: You don't check for the other being "far" from the one that is close, so `!cIsCose` proves that `c` must be "far from a" but it does not prove that `c` is far from `b`.

Comment: @Chris I made the same mistake you did and misread the problem, it does mention comparing both.

"while the  other is "far", differing from **both other values** by 2 or more"

Comment: @AgentOrange See revised code, now success is based on only one of the three relationships being close and the other two not being close.

Answer (score 0):

You can break this down into two possible situation when it's `true`

1. `b` is close and `c` is far
2. `c` is close and `b` is far

Now, what does 1. mean?

- `b` is close - `Math.abs(a-b) <= 1`
- `c` is far - `Math.abs(a-c) >= 2 && Math.abs(b-c) >= 2`

So we end up with

```
if (Math.abs(a - b) <= 1 && Math.abs(a - c) >= 2 && Math.abs(b - c) >= 2) {
    return true;
}
```

Now apply the same logic to the second condition:

```
if (Math.abs(a - c) <= 1 && Math.abs(a - b) >= 2 && Math.abs(b - c) >= 2) {
    return true;
}
```

So the final method looks like:

```
public static boolean myMethod(int a, int b, int c) {
    if (Math.abs(a - b) <= 1 && Math.abs(a - c) >= 2 && Math.abs(b - c) >= 2) {
        return true;
    }
    if (Math.abs(a - c) <= 1 && Math.abs(a - b) >= 2 && Math.abs(b - c) >= 2) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Output:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(myMethod(1, 2, 10));
    System.out.println(myMethod(1, 2, 3));
    System.out.println(myMethod(4, 1, 3));
}
true
false
true
```